# I can't get the value in my select form and use it in my Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'yr1' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SpesGraduate(Int32)' in 'SPESMS.Controllers.ReportsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters**

> Here is the View:

```
<form action="/spesms/Reports/SpesGraduate" method="get" >
     <select name="yr1" id="yr1">
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
          <option value="2021">2021</option>
          <option value="2022">2022</option>
      </select>
  </form>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('select').on('change', function () {
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
                location.reload();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

> here is the controller

```
public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int yr1)
        {
            int poid = GlobalHelper.UserPO(Session["UserPO"].ToString());
            int implYear = (int)Session["ImplementYear"];
            int selyr1 = yr1;
        }
```

Comment: Haven't seen you are not extracting the value in your controller

Comment: So are you trying to get value of `name="yr1" id="yr1"` dropdown within your controller?

Comment: no sir i just tried to put an id because I'm out of solution

Comment: Not sure what you want to get from your controller. When you would change the dropdown what do you expect your controller to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't get the value in my select form and use it in my Controller

I have reproduced your issue in my side but not sure why you are getting the error, In my test I haven't get any error as yours. However, the reason for getting null parameter for using `location.reload();` which reloading your page soon you submit the request. I have get rid of that line and its working as expected and I am getting the value accordingly.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int yr1)
        {
            int poid = GlobalHelper.UserPO(Session["UserPO"].ToString());
            int implYear = (int)Session["ImplementYear"];
            int selyr1 = yr1;
        }
```

Note: No change I made here just it as yours.

View & Script:

```cs
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('select').on('change', function () {
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
                //location.reload(); 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Note: Everything would be same just ommit `location.reload();` which reloading your page soon you submit request thus, you cannot see the impact.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Its quite alright and glad to assist you on this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change

```
public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int yr1)
```

to

```
public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int? yr1)
```

I had the same issue and I resolved it like that.

Comment: Whats the difference  between `public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int yr1)` and `public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int? yr1)`?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int yr1) 
in this case it requires a value which is null so its not working, that's why in case of nullable we use "?" with int .
like --> public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int? yr1)

Comment: change this:
 int selyr1 = yr1;
to this:
int? selyr1 = yr1;
in your controller
@MarkJohnCapistrano

Answer (score 1):

Change form method to `POST`

```
 <form action="/spesms/Reports/SpesGraduate" method="POST" >
     <select name="yr1" id="yr1">
          <option value="2019">2019</option>
          <option value="2020">2020</option>
          <option value="2021">2021</option>
          <option value="2022">2022</option>
      </select>
  </form>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('select').on('change', function () {
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            });
        });
  </script>
```

the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SpesGraduate(int yr1)
{
    int poid = GlobalHelper.UserPO(Session["UserPO"].ToString());
    int implYear = (int)Session["ImplementYear"];
    int selyr1 = yr1;
}
```